# TLE is not inserted in every page of the AFP when the table overflow

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am trying to add TLE to my AFP using Apache FOP. I am able to add it successfully on the first page sequence.
The first page sequence has static data and does not change.
The issue is with my second page sequence where in the table overflows and creates dynamic number of pages.
The TLE added here appears as a group and not on every page.

```
                <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:rx="http://www.renderx.com/XSL/Extensions" xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions" xmlns:afp="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions/afp" >

                <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="1.5cm" margin-bottom="2cm" margin-right="0.5cm">
                    <fo:region-body/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4-normal" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="1.2cm" margin-bottom="1.25cm" margin-left="1.5cm" margin-right="0.5cm">
                    <fo:region-body region-name="body" margin-top="3cm"/>
                    <fo:region-before region-name="xsl-region-before"/>
                    <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="blank" page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm" margin-top="20mm" margin-bottom="20mm" margin-left="25mm" margin-right="25mm">
                    <fo:region-body/>
                    <fo:region-before region-name="header-blank" extent="297mm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
                <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="A4-first">
                    <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference blank-or-not-blank="not-blank" master-reference="A4-normal"/>
                        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference blank-or-not-blank="blank" master-reference="blank"/>
                    </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                </fo:page-sequence-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
```

The is how i have added my TLE:

```
<!--This page sequence has no issue with TLE and TLE appears on page 1 and 2-->
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4" initial-page-number="1" id="first">
<xsl:call-template name="TLE"/>
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
</fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
<!-- I have another page sequence here where the table overflows and created n number of pages-->
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-first">
<xsl:call-template name="TLE"/>
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
</fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>


<xsl:template name="TLE">
<afp:tag-logical-element name="CUSTOMER_NAME" value="Customername"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Please ignore the syntax errors.
The output is something like this :

```
CUSTOMER_NAME
<value>
  GRP:PGP00001 - Has TLE
   PG 1:PGN00001 - Has TLE

  GRP:PGP00002 - Has TLE
   PG 2: PGN00002 - Has TLE
   PG 3: PGN00003 - No TLE
   PG 4: PGN00004 - No TLE
```

How do i add TLE on all pages?